# AWS Lambda can't connect to AWS SQS (VPC Endpoint)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I have an **AWS Lambda** connected to my RDS instance in a **VPC** via Security Group(s). Putting my AWS Lambda inside a VPC means it has no access to the public internet unless I create a VPC Endpoint. Since my Lambda is inside a VPC, it needs a VPC Endpoint connected to the **SQS service API**. I have made a VPC Endpoint for the SQS service API with a separate `Security Group` *(SQS-Lambda-SG)*. When running my code in AWS, it successfully connects to my RDS, but gets stuck when attempting to send a message to SQS.

> My lambda is a .NET 6 application using the **MassTransit** package for sending messages to the SQS. This works fine in my EC2 with the same logic and settings as seen below, but not in my lambda.

I have also made a separate `Security Group` *(Lambda-SQS-Endpoint-SG)* for my Lambda.

The *Lambda-SQS-Endpoint-SG* has the following Inbound & Outbound rules:

- HTTPS - 443 - SQS-Lambda-SG as source `[Inbound]`
- HTTPS - 443 - SQS-Lambda-SG as source `[Outbound]`

The *SQS-Lambda-SG* has the following Inbound & Outbound rules:

- HTTPS - 443 - Lambda-SQS-Endpoint-SG as source `[Inbound]`
- HTTPS - 443 - Some-EC2-SG as source `[Inbound]`
- HTTPS - 443 - Lambda-SQS-Endpoint-SG as source `[Outbound]`

The *Some-EC2-SG* is necessary since that one is in the same VPC and needs access to SQS as well and the Some-EC2-SG has the following Inbound & Outbound rules:

- PostgreSQL - 5432 - **API-SG** as source `[Inbound]`
- HTTPS - 443 - SQS-Lambda-SG as source `[Outbound]`

The *API-SG* has the following Inbound & Outbound rules:

- HTTP - 80 - 0.0.0.0/0 as source `[Inbound]`
- All traffic - All - 0.0.0.0/0 as source `[Outbound]`

> The API-SG belongs to my API that runs on my `EC2 instance` inside the VPC, and receives calls from my `Load Balancer`. But it's further irrelevant to my issue with my lambda.

I have included the security groups and even, perhaps further irrelevant, related security groups just to show the complete traffic. I don't know why my lambda can't connect/send a message to SQS. It worked before I put it inside a VPC, which is obvious, but now it's in a VPC, and it doesn't. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: You haven't mentioned enabling private DNS on the endpoint. Did you do that? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/interface-endpoints.html#enable-private-dns-names

Comment: The Security Group connected to the Lambda function is traditionally given an Outbound rule of "Allow All" since it is trusted code. The Security Group on a VPC Endpoint does not require any Outbound rules since all traffic goes _into_ the endpoint and return traffic is stateful. For testing purposes, I recommend that you temporarily open the Lambda and Endpoint Security Groups to "Allow All" Inbound and Outbound to test whether it works. If it does work, then you know that the problem was caused by a Security Group and you can add back the rules individually to identify the problem.

Comment: Have you assigned a resource policy to your SQS Queue?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes, I enabled it at the moment I created the endpoint

Comment: @JohnRotenstein very frustrating that it still doesn't work...

Comment: @victorm It should be correct, I didn't change anything, because it worked before I brought changes in my Lambda for RDS access.

Comment: Btw, I managed to fix it. It was nothing above, since MassTransit works with SQS & SNS, my queues are subscribed to SNS topics, I needed to create a VPC endpoint for SNS as well. That did the trick.

Comment: Feel free to create an Answer to your own Question.